# HTML button changes into another button when clicked on the same div

Tags: javascript, html

your help is really appreciated :)

I have my project in HTML and javascript and i need to create a button that once clicked, it will be replaced by another button and the button appeared will also be replaced by the previous button once it was clicked.

here is my javascript code and HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button id="create">create</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#create').click(function() {
            $('#container').html('<button id="again">again</button><button id="cancel">cancel</button>');
        });

        $('#again').click(function() {
            $('#container').html('<div><button id="create">create</button></div>');
        });

        $('#cancel').click(function() {
            $('#container').html('<div id="cancel">cancel</div>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or try this link instead: http://codepen.io/enrison09/pen/hwlBA

thank you alot in advance! :)

Comment: Instead of going JS wild, you could toggle 1 body class and use CSS to show/hide the correct button.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/gq5051fn/ Keeps your JS and DOM cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the click function only sets the event handlers to what DOM elements are available at the moment it is called. This means you won't be able to use it for anything that is added to the DOM afterwards.

The solution is to use the on() function instead, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#create', function() {
  $('#container').html('<button id="again">again</button><button id="cancel">cancel</button>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#again', function() {
  $('#container').html('<div><button id="create">create</button></div>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#cancel', function() {
  $('#container').html('<div id="cancel">cancel</div>');
});
```

[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) works with elements that are dynamically added to the DOM.

See your example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLjki

However, there are nicer ways to do this (like having all the needed buttons in the DOM the whole time, and just toggling which are visible and which are not at what stage).

Comment: You're welcome! It's quite a common issue, now you know how to deal with it.

Comment: by the way sir, if i were to add a delay (in seconds) before the button shows, how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, of course. See it here, I've done it just for the #create button, you do the rest: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEsAI

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm new in javascript, and want to do many things like setting delays and make the new button appear in more dramatic effect like fading-in

Comment: thank you very much! you helped me alot! i'm really grateful to you sir! i hope you can help me again next time!

Comment: No problem, sir! Welcome to StackOverflow. And here is an example with fades: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pzsdK Remember: `setTimeout` is the most basic JavaScript function for timeouts (delays), while jQuery has a lot of those helper functions like `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, etc. which are still doable in plain JavaScript.

Comment: holy!! youre really awesome sir!! i'll study and be a great programmer just like you! add me to your fans list sir! thanks again!! :D CHEERS!!

Answer (score 1):

What about hiding and showing them instead of removing and creating?

```
<div id="container">
    <button style="display:none" id="again">again</button>
    <button id="create">create</button>
</div>
<script>
    $("#create").click(function () {
        if($('#create').html()=='create'){
            $('#again').show();
            $(this).html('cancel')
        }
        else{
            $('#again').hide();
            $(this).html("create");
        }        
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8at2nbx7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a structure like this :

```
var $create = $('<button id="create">create</button>');
var $again = $('<button id="again">again</button>');
var $cancel = $('<button id="cancel">cancel</button>');

$('body').on('click', '#create', function() {
  $(this).remove();
  $('#container').append($again).append($cancel);
});

$('body').on('click', '#again', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.find('button').remove();
  $parent.append($create);
});

$('body').on('click', '#cancel', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.find('button').remove();
  $parent.append($cancel);
});
```

The on function replace live into jQuery v1.7+ : http://api.jquery.com/on.

Create button at the top of the process reduce memory cost and DOM work.